# PUSH operation In stack

Tags: assembly

Suppose I have to execute the following instruction in Assembly:(x86)

```
 **PUSH AL
   SUB CL,AL  
   PUSH CL**
```

*where the value of CL=34H, AL=34H*

If so, can I push CL onto the stack?
And will the ESP be decremented if the above instruction is executed?
Will the zero flag be set?

CL will become 0 for the above code, if so, can I push it onto the stack? Will this affect the stack pointer?

Comment: An 8086 doesn't have an `ESP` register, is only has `SP`. It's not until the 32-bit x86 processors that there was an `ESP`.

Comment: There is no push cl instruction. You can only push 16 bit registers or memory operands on the 8086.

Comment: @fuz what about in the extended x86 version?

Comment: @BhavyaJinaraj No version of x86 can push an 8 bit register.

Answer (score 0):

The values of `AL` and `CL` have no bearing on whether or not you can push them onto the stack.  What matters is only the stack segment `SS` and the stack pointer `SP` (or `ESP` or `RSP`, depending on the operation mode).  If the stack pointer points inside the stack and the size of the register fits between the stack pointer and the stack limit, then you can push the register.

That said, there is no actual instruction in x86 to push an 8-bit register.

---

When you push, `SP` gets decremented.  The register that you pushed remains unchanged.